# ¿Puede el pluscuamperfecto indicar anterioridad a un suceso presente?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Según veo, la RAE indica que el [pretérito pluscuamperfecto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U8HCFgV):

> sitúa la acción, el proceso o el estado expresados por el verbo en un momento anterior a otro, **igualmente pasado**. [énfasis mío]

Recientemente un amigo me contó una anecdota que me causa duda; dijo:

> Justo *había llegado* al hotel cuando *veo* que no tengo mis maletas.

En esta oración utiliza *había llegado* (pluscuamperfecto) pero lo expresa como anterior al *veo*´ (presente).

Tengo claro que toda su anecdota se refiere a un suceso pasado, pero eso lo entiendo gracias al contexto y no por la oración en si mismo.

¿Esta mal dicha su oración?
¿Siempre se clasifica como pluscuamperfecto aunque se antepone a un verbo conjugado en presente?  ¿o recibe otra clasificación?

Answer (score 5):

Es más bien que tu amigo está usando el llamado **presente histórico** o **presente narrativo**.

A pesar de que dice «veo», la acción expresada por dicho verbo no acaece en la actualidad, sino en lo que tal vez podríamos llamar la actualidad o el presente del tiempo narrado (que, como sabemos, está en el pasado).

Es cierto que lo normal sería una de las dos opciones:

> *Narración pretérita (con eje temporal lastrado en el presente)*
>   Justo **había llegado** al hotel cuando **vi** que no **tenía** mis maletas.
>
> *Narración presente (con eje temporal lastrado en la acción descrita)*
>   Justo **he llegado** (*o bien* **llegué**) al hotel cuando **veo** que no **tengo** mis maletas.

No obstante, a veces por razones estilísticas (y especialmente en el habla cotidiana e informal), el eje temporal se cambia incluso dentro de una oración, tal y como es el caso en la oración.  Empieza describiendo algo en el pasado, pero probablemente alrededor de la palabra *cuando*, yo le imagino actuando y gestionando con las manos y cara su reacción de buscar y no encontrar las maletas.  Ello justificaría bien el cambio brusco al presente narrativo.